# Is there a way to avoid getting an exception from a REST request in flutter?

Tags: http, flutter

I've developed a small app on flutter with a bottom navbar, if you press one of the items of the navbar it will take you to a screen where, as soon as it opens, it performs an http GET to retrieve a quote from an external API. The problem is, after clicking the item on the navbar there's an error that shows for a brief amount of time probably due to the fact that the request as not been finished so it cannot display the result. Is there a way to avoid this?

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

class ClientsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ClientsPageState createState() => _ClientsPageState();
}

class _ClientsPageState extends State<ClientsPage> {
  Map data;

  Future<String> getData() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get("https://api.kanye.rest");
    this.setState(() {
      data = json.decode(response.body);
    });
    return "success";
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.getData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: const Text('Clients Page',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.yellow)),
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        ),
        body: new Container(
            child: new Center(
                child: new Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
              new Text(data["quote"]),
              new RaisedButton(
                  child: new Text("Kanye Quote"), onPressed: getData)
            ]))));
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @João Dias! Please do not post your code as screenshots, paste it into the question. If you select your code and press the `{}`-Button, it will be displayed in monospace.

Comment: If i am not being clear enough please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error because `Map data` you defined hasn't got data from api before you access it in your Text widget. For this you need to use FutureBuilder which will wait until your request is completed and then show data.You can learn more about [FutureBuilder here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

```
class ClientsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ClientsPageState createState() => _ClientsPageState();
}

class _ClientsPageState extends State<ClientsPage> {
  Map data;

  Future<String> getData() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get("https://api.kanye.rest");
    this.setState(() {
      data = json.decode(response.body);
    });
    return "success";
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.getData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: const Text('Clients Page',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.yellow)),
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        ),
        body: new Container(
            child: new Center(
                child: new Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      FutureBuilder(
                        future: getData(),
                          builder:(context,snapshot){
                          if(snapshot.hasData){
                            return Text(data["quote"]);
                          }else{
                            return CircularProgressIndicator();
                          }
                         }),
                      new RaisedButton(
                          child: new Text("Kanye Quote"), onPressed: getData)
                    ]))));
  }
}
```